# Hibernate Query wont pick up parameters

Tags: sql, hibernate, parameters, hql

This issue is causing unbelievable frustrations. Basically it took me 1 hr to set up an entire hibernate project. But this issue is holding me up for nearly 5 hrs now and Ive been continuously at it.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM " + FieldData.class.getName() +" ff WHERE ff.fieldData = :fieldData");

query.setParameter("fieldData", fieldData);
```

No matter what I do (I mean seriously) I get **IllegalArgumentException**. I tried query.setLong() as well since fieldData happens to be Long value.

I checked the getters and setters and they look like this

```
@Column(..I cant reveal mappings)
getFieldData()
{
   return this.fieldData;
}

setFieldData(Long fieldData)
{
   return this.fieldData;
}
```

Finally the variable declaration itself is like this:

```
 private Long fieldData;
```

What is going on here? and why is it so **HARD** to fix this issue. Aren't these frameworks mature enough to work without bugs? I am using Hibernate 3.4. Or is it all I can expect with open source stuff?

Lastly the parameter meta data object used by query.createQuery() has no variables it picked up inside it.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Id really like to know I am the one making mistake and nothing wrong with the framework - that is really good news for me.

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter ----> This is the exception I get with query.setParameter()

Comment: with query.setLong() I get the same exception however it complains in different language (wordings)...

Comment: Have you mapped your entity with a DB table? Because a generic error on named parameter has caused by that.

Comment: @JoeTaras    Yes I did. There were few mistakes there. I had imported hibernate annotations instead of javax. Hard to detect but it created some issues. The bigger issue was that I had not included the package information of my pojos in the HibernateUtil class while creating the sessionFactory. That was throwing all kinds of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after much hard work I found the issue for this problem. I had not included the POJO packaging name while creating hibernate sessions. That was causing all kinds of parameter binding problems. The worst part about Hibernate is that it throws exceptions that are throughout misleading. It was going to the extent to throwing QueryParameterException when it could not even resolve the class in the first place. I think they got to work on this. It makes Hibernate persistence so hard to use for development and the entire setup incredibly fragile for any minor change.

Comment: Besides this the package information I included inside hibernate.cfg.xml was not being picked up by the config builders. It did pick up the file itself successfully but could not resolve the package information present in the file.